# VIF doesn't show up values for categorical variables

Tags: r, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

My data set contains few varibales which I converted to factor as I wanted them to be in that format. To start with, I wanted to check the importance of each variable and check for multicollinearity. But when I run code, I get NA values for all those factor variables.
[image]

Does vif doesn't work for categorical variables?

Answer (score 4):

Variance Inflation Factors are defined on the level of *regressors*. A categorical factor with $k$ levels will (usually) be dummy-coded into $k-1$ separate boolean dummies, so you might, if at all, get $k-1$ VIFs.

However, [collinearity between categorical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multicollinearity+categorical-data?sort=votes&pageSize=50) is much less well understood than collinearity between numerical regressors. See also here: [Collinearity between categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18084/1352) So I wouldn't be surprised if your software package made a conscious decision not to output VIFs for categorical data.

Comment: say if i don't convert them into factors manually and just run VIF on raw data, would that be a good step to know variable importance?

Comment: VIF is not defined for categorical data. You cannot run VIF on it.