# R - checking colinearity of 3 categorial and 1 continuous variables

Tags: r, regression, multicollinearity, spearman-rho

I have the following variables which are expected to influence the dependent variable *kg waste*:

*turnover* (continuous),
*restaurant type* (either D or I),
*operation* (either P or N),
*owner* (either M or F).

To analyse the effect of these variables on *kg waste* I would like to investigate first the collinearity between these variables prior to running a model. However, this is where I run into problems.. pairwise scatterplots do not tell me a lot and when I run this code:

```
cor.test(df$restauranttype,df$turnover,method="spearman")
```

I get this error message:

```
'x' must be a numeric vector
```

How do I explore collinearity of continuous and categorical independent variables?

What model would you suggest using?

Comment: I guess I need to perform chi-square test to detect multicolinearity?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/285725/82122). Unfortunately, collinearity for categorical variables is not well defined (So variance inflation factor (VIF) in a regression equation would not make much sens). A chi-square test would make more sense in this case.